# Get name of control that calls macro in Powerpoint

Tags: c#, vsto, powerpoint, add-in

Is there a way in VBA for PowerPoint or C# COM AddIn, to identify the control that calls a macro or the control that is active (figuring that it has just been clicked)?

I know about

```
Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWindow.Selection
```

, but that doesn't work when you're in presentation mode and I can't find anything under

```
Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActivePresentation
```

EDIT:
I need to get the control or its name, so that I can use the same Sub for multiple controls.

Example:

```
Public Sub RespondToControl(Control sender) 
    Dim AddIn As COMAddIn 
    Dim automationObject As Object 
    Set AddIn = Application.COMAddIns("MyAddIn") 
    Set automationObject = AddIn.object 
    Call automationObject.DoSomethingBasedOnNameOfControl(sender.Name) 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the controls from the developer toolbox (command buttons, checkboxes and the like) then the code in each individual control's Click event will run when the control is clicked during a slide show.

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
MsgBox "You clicked CheckBox1"
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
MsgBox "You clicked CommandButton1"
End Sub
```

Did you mean some other type of controls?

What exactly do you need to accomplish?

Comment: Thanks for your reply that I didn't see until now. Unfortunately it doesn't solve my problem, as you don't identify the calling control, you just call a code specific for the control.   

I need to get the control or its name, so that I can use the same Sub for multiple controls.     
  
Example:   
Public Sub RespondToControl(Control sender)   
    Dim AddIn As COMAddIn   
    Dim automationObject As Object   
    Set AddIn = Application.COMAddIns("MyAddIn")   
    Set automationObject = AddIn.object   
    Call automationObject.DoSomethingBasedOnNameOfControl(sender.Name)   
End Sub

Comment: Sorry for the awful formatting of the above, that was my first comment here and the markdown for linebreak (two spaces at end), doesn't seem to work for me?